# glUniformMatrix4fv OpenTK equivalent

Tags: opengl, glsl, opentk

Very simple and quick question which surprisingly I couldn't find an answer to over the internet: what is the equivalent of glUniformMatrixfv for opentk? I've browsed all the 7 overloads of GL.UniformMatrix4 and none of them seems correct to me and/or I have found any example usage for.

E.g. if I have a

`Matrix4[] matrices;`

variable (properly initialized etc..) that I want to map on a

`mat4 matrices[2];`

in glsl, which GL.UniformMatrix4 overload should I use?

P.S. Using OpenTK.Next NuGet package version 1.1.1616.8959

Answer (score 1):

According to GL spec:

```
void glUniformMatrix4fv(GLint location,
                        GLsizei count,
                        GLboolean transpose,
                        const GLfloat *value);

*location*
Specifies the location of the uniform value to be modified.

*count*
Specifies the number of matrices that are to be modified. 
This should be 1 if the targeted uniform variable is not an array of matrices, 
and 1 or more if it is an array of matrices.

*transpose*
Specifies whether to transpose the matrix 
as the values are loaded into the uniform variable. Must be GL_FALSE.

*value*
Specifies a pointer to an array of count values
that will be used to update the specified uniform variable.
```

So in my opinion (I've never used OpenTK before) you can use the following function:

```
static unsafe void OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.GL.UniformMatrix4(Int32 location,
                                                             Int32 count,
                                                             bool transpose,
                                                             Double * value)
```

Which has the same parameters as the C++ equivalent. Just pass the proper parameters to this function and everything should be ok:

```
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.GL.UniformMatrix4(matrices_location,
                                          2        /* count - 2 matrices */,
                                          false    /* transpose */,
                                          matrices /* ref, pointer */);
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. I was looking for an ad hoc Matrix4[] overload or at least a non unsafe one. I found out that the best way to do this is basically unfolding the matrix in an array and pass by value the float[]. If you added this to your answer I would be pleased to mark your response as correct. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the best way to do it, but you could just unroll the matrix in a for loop that adds each element to a `float[]`.

```
private float[] Matrix4ToArray(Matrix4 matrix)
{
    float[] data = new float[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            data[i*4+j] = matrix[i, j];

        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Copying the data as a block would be cheaper, or something like a member access function to the underlying data on the OpenTK API side, but I couldn't find any, and the above worked well enough for my needs.